# management.azure.com query fails when using MonitorManagementClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I am using MonitorManagementClient and code like this

```
     string startDate = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-intervalInMinutes).ToString("o"));
        string endDate = string.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
                    var metrics = await monitoringClient.Metrics.ListAsync(
                                     resourceUri: app.Id,//.ToString().TrimStart("/".ToCharArray()),
                                    timespan: startDate + "/" + endDate,
                                    interval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalInMinutes),
                                    metricnames: "HealthCheckStatus",
                                    resultType: ResultType.Data,
                                    cancellationToken: CancellationToken.None);
```

the overall path becomes like this

```
https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?timespan=2022-10-08T03%3A35%3A00.0448662%2B00%3A00%2F2022-10-08T03%3A40%3A00.0448710%2B00%3A00&interval=PT5M&metricnames=HealthCheckStatus&resultType=Data&api-version=2018-01-01
```

I am  getting a 400 bad request error.
and app insights shows this message

> There may be telemetry recorded by management.azure.com, but you do not have access to it. If management.azure.com is part of your application, check with your subscription administrator for access.

Does it looks like something is wrong with the code ? Because same code works locally. only not working when Azure function is published.

Is there a way to see original error generated by. management.azure.com ?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to use Utc time . Thats why it was working locally but not in published mode.